# How to create a Integer.TYPE(int.class) array by frida js

Tags: java, arrays, frida

I have a question in `java.lang.Class.getMethod`.

```
public Method getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException 
{
    return getMethod(name, parameterTypes, true); 
}
```

The second parameter need a `[java.lang.Object];` type, and `java` code like this:

```
getMethod("say", new Class[]{String.class,int.class});
getMethod("say", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE,Integer.TYPE});
```

so How can I create this `array` using `js` or other ways ?

In addition,I created a `obj array` like this:

```
var Integerclass = Java.use("java.lang.Integer");
var objectArr = Java.array('Ljava.lang.Class;[Integerclass.TYPE,Integerclass.TYPE]);
```

but I got a **invalid argument value** error, how to resolve it ？:

> {'type': 'error', 'description': 'Error: invalid argument value', 'stack': 'Error: invalid argument value\n at frida/node_modules/frida-java/lib/env.js:515\n at frida/node_modules/frida-java/lib/class-factory.js:2592\n at toJniObjectArray (frida/node_modules/frida-java/lib/class-factory.js:2640)\n at java.js:4489\n at frida/node_modules/frida-java/lib/class-factory.js:743\n at [anon] (script1.js:28)\n at input:1', 'fileName': 'frida/node_modules/frida-java/lib/env.js', 'lineNumber': 515, 'columnNumber': 1}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you provide some more context about what you're trying to achieve? Most of your question is about Java, but then there's just a tiny bit about Javascript with no other context. How does Javascript interact with the Java code you've got?

Answer (score 0):

The **java** code using reflection would be:

```
int length = 42;
int[] arr = (int[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(int.class, length);
```

Where `int.class` corresponds with the constant `Integer.TYPE`.

You can use reflection as:

```
klazz.getMethod("avg", int[].class, int.class);
```

JavaScript can use wrap this.

---

***My guess at JavaScript:***

```
var StringClass = Java.use("java.lang.String.class");
var IntClass = Java.use("int.class");
var IntArrayClass = Java.use("int[].class");
var objectArr = Java.array([IntClass, IntArrayClass]);
var objectArr = Java.array([StringClass, IntClass]);

getMethod("say", objectArr);
```

Comment: I can understand what you say by java,bu now my question is how to use js to create int.class in frida . you said "JavaScript can use wrap this." what's the meaning？could you write all of this js code ？

Comment: Honestly admitted: I have no idea. In general I simply use JS on the java object: `obj.say(13)` for a java say method.

Comment: yes,if you use var IntClass = Java.use("int.class"); in frida ,the error is :
```
 Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "int.class" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.cryptutils-5MsTN2JCT4sK1cVzycxn0g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.cryptutils-5MsTN2JCT4sK1cVzycxn0g==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a 'int':

```
Integer = Java.use("java.lang.Integer")
int = Integer.class.getField("TYPE").get(null)
```

hope you can work it

int number seems can't be recognized as a 'java.lang.Object', but a method (param has a 'int') can fit with it automatically.
here is a example:

```
var iActivityManager = ActivityManagerNative.class.getMethod("getDefault", null).invoke(null, null)
var method_startUserInBackground = ActivityManagerNative.class.getMethod("startUserInBackground", [int])
var isOK = method_startUserInBackground.invoke(iActivityManager, [Integer.$new(10)])
```

getMethod - use 'int' ; sendParam - use 'Integer'